# embedded-cassandra not working in java 21

Tags: embedded-cassandra

I recently upgraded my build to java 21 from 11. I updated my pom to the latst version of embedded-cassandra. When I run my in-memory tests, I get the following error:

```
2024-03-20 19:01:59.428(GMT) ERROR Unrecognized VM option 'UseBiasedLocking'
2024-03-20 19:01:59.431(GMT) ERROR Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
2024-03-20 19:01:59.431(GMT) ERROR Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Is there a solution for this problem? Does embedded-cassandra support java 21?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about Embedded Cassandra itself. As far as I know, Apache Cassandra does not support jdk21 so far.
You can try to use 5.0-beta1

```java
 import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;

import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.Cassandra;
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.CassandraBuilder;
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.Settings;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cassandra cassandra = new CassandraBuilder()
                .version("5.0-beta1")
                .addSystemProperty("java.security.manager", "allow").build();

        cassandra.start();
        try {
            Settings settings = cassandra.getSettings();
            try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
                    .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress(settings.getAddress(), settings.getPort()))
                    .withLocalDatacenter("datacenter1")
                    .build()) {
                //
            }
        }
        finally {
            cassandra.stop();
        }
    }

}
```